# How can I change class depending on child component function call in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vuejs and I found this issue when i'm trying to do the hamburger menu function.

To get simplify I have added code spinets below

App.vue

```
<keep-alive>        
    <div class="body-wrapper" v-bind:class="menuOpenCls">
         <div class="hamburger-wrapper" v-on:click="mobileMenu()">
              <div class="hamburger-menu">
                   <span></span>
                   <span></span>
                   <span></span>
                   <span></span>
               </div>
          </div>        
     <router-view v-bind:headerMenu="headerMenu" v-bind:footerMenu="footerMenu" v-bind:ShowSmileys="ShowSmileys"></router-view>
     </div>
</keep-alive>
```

...

```
data() {
    return {
        menuOpen:''
    }
},
```

...

```
methods: {
      mobileMenu: function() {
          this.menuOpen = !this.menuOpen;
      }
}
```

...

```
computed:  {
    menuOpenCls: function() {
        return this.menuOpen ? 'menuopen' : '';
    }    
}
```

Header.vue

```
<header>        
        <nav v-if="headerMenu"> 
           <ul class="menu">    
               <li><router-link v-bind:to="item.Url" exact v-on:click="**<<function to change class on App.vue>>**>{{item.Name}</router-link></li>
           </ul>    
        </nav>      
</header>
```

I want to change (toggle) class name on App.vue (class where body-wrapper is in) depending on click event in Header.vue menu link. How can I achieve this. Can Any one help?

Comment: Be more specific, what do you wanna achieve and what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to pass data between components that are not necessarily related [parent/child].

Have you tried using the Vue `EventBus`? A good example: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

I'm posting the relevant bits here [that I use in couple of my VueJS projects for exactly the same purpose as yours: a click somewhere toggles a CSS class elsewhere :-)]

In your `main.js`:

```
const EventBus = new Vue()
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $bus: {
        get: function () {
          return EventBus
        }
    }
})
```

The click event in `Header.vue` would emit an event on the global bus:

```
this.$bus.$emit('toggle-class-name')
```

and `App.vue` would listen for the event and do what's needed:

```
created () {
    ...
    ...
    this.$bus.$on('toggle-class-name', () => {
        // toggle the class name here
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you gvk! :) Your explanation helped me to found the solution. You save my day!